# hiding non-generic base class property in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, return-type

What is the standard pattern for hiding non-generic base class property or method in generic class?

I Have 2 solution what is actually do the same but different approach. Solution one use more memory because the base and derived class reference the same object and Solution two is slower because the casting.(or maybe i wrong?)

Base classes:

```
public class MyDataBase {}

public class MyDataDerived : MyDataBase {}

 public class BaseFoo
 {
     private readonly MyDataBase _data;
     public MyDataBase Data { get { return _data; } }

     public BaseFoo(MyDataBase data) {
      _data = data;
  }
}
```

Solution 1:

```
public class GenericFooWithHiding<T> : BaseFoo where T : MyDataBase
{
     private readonly T _data;

     public GenericFooWithHiding(T data) : base(data) { _data = data; }

     public new T Data { get { return _data; } }
 }
```

Solution 2:

```
public class GenericFooWithCasting<T> : BaseFoo where T : MyDataBase
{
     public GenericFooWithCasting(T data) : base(data) {}

     public new T Data { get { return base.Data as T; } }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose why you have generics here? You are making it where T can only be that one type, you could use the MyDataBase type and still send a MyDataBaseDerived to the constructor.

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities: `T` can be any type derived from `MyDataBase`. The question is how to change the return type of the property into `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go second (cast) approach if I were to chose from these two: having the same data stored in more than one place is pretty much guaranteed way to get them out of sync. So I'd play casting cost (unlikely to be significant), if performance is important - measure and verify.

Side note: I would try avoid `new` properties as it will cause confusion what is called depending on what variable type you have. Making base class' `Data` property protected may be potential solution in particular sample.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3

Reverse the relationship of inheritance between `BaseFoo` and `GenericFoo<T>`, thus the use of generic becomes significant and doesn't need to hide at all.

```
public class MyDataBase {
}

public class MyDataDerived: MyDataBase {
}

public class GenericFoo<T> where T: MyDataBase {
    public GenericFoo(T data=default(T)) {
    }

    public T Data {
        get {
            return _data;
        }
    }

    protected readonly T _data;
}

public class DerivedFoo: GenericFoo<MyDataDerived> {
    public DerivedFoo(MyDataDerived data=default(MyDataDerived))
        : base(data) {
    }
}

public class BaseFoo: GenericFoo<MyDataBase> {
    public BaseFoo(MyDataBase data=default(MyDataBase))
        : base(data) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you cannot change the type `BaseFoo` since otherwise you could make it generic in the first place.

I would not use `new` to change the return type since this might get confusing. For example: what is the type of `data` in this code snippet?

```
GenericFoo<MyDataDerived> foo = new GenericFoo<MyDataDerived>(new MyDataDerived());
var data = ((BaseFoo)foo).Data;
```

It is `MyDataBase` (the call goes to `BaseFoo`). If however you have a virtual property in `BaseFoo` which is overridden in `GenericFoo`, which will be called?:

```
public class BaseFoo
{
    public virtual MyDataBase MoreData
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }
}

public class GenericFoo<T> : BaseFoo where T : MyDataBase
{
    public override MyDataBase MoreData
    {
        get
        {
            return _someOtherData;
        }
    }
}

// which property is called?
var data = ((BaseFoo)foo).MoreData;
```

This time the call goes to `GenericFoo`. Since this is usually the expected behaviour I would suggest not to use `new`.

I would implement a method in `GenericFoo` to avoid the use of `new` (and I would use a cast):

```
public class GenericFoo<T> : BaseFoo
    where T : MyDataBase
{
    public T GetData()
    {
        return (T)base.Data;
    }
}
```